# Get target/recipient of Akka ask

Tags: scala, akka

I'm using the following snippet of code in my Akka classic project.

```
(persistence ? Persist("a", Some(100), 123)) (100.milliseconds)
  .mapTo[Persisted]
  .recover(ex => Failure(ex.getMessage()))
  .pipeTo(self)
```

When I handle the success response of this `ask` then the sender is `self`. How can I get the sender of the response to this `ask`? In other words, how can I get the address of the target/ recipient actor here?

Edit:

It's quite obvious that `persistence` is the target of the ask. But what I really want to know is if there's a way to have `persistence` address be available through the `pipeTo`. Let's say there is an array of `persistence` than I wouldn't know which `Persist` message came from which `persistence`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your question.  `persistence` is the target of the ask.

It's possible that `persistence` is delegating work to another actor (e.g. a worker in a pool), but that would reveal implementation details and tbh is probably not going to be that useful (which is part of why the ask pattern doesn't propagate sender).

If it's a protocol you control, explicitly adding an `ActorRef` to the response is guaranteed to work.

You could roll your own version of the ask pattern which propagates the sender, though as noted above, it's probably not going to be that useful.

EDIT: to propagate `persistence` into the forwarded reply, the easiest is to `map` the `Future` result of the ask into something which bundles `persistence` with the result (as a sort of correlation ID), like:

```scala
(persistence ? Persist("a", Some(100), 123)) (100.milliseconds)
  .mapTo[Persisted]
  .map { response => persistence -> response }
  .recoverWith { ex => persistence -> Failure(ex.getMessage) }
  .pipeTo(self)
```

The messages that get sent will be tuples of an `ActorRef` and either `Persisted` or `Failure`, so you'd match them in your receive with something like

```scala
case (persistenceTarget, Persisted(...)) => ???
case (persistenceTarget, Failure(msg)) => ???
```

(You can also explicitly change the protocol into something that includes the `ActorRef`: a tuple is perhaps a little too primitive, but is convenient for this answer without knowing more details about the protocol)

Note that if `persistence` is a field in your `Actor`, it might change between when you send the ask and when you execute `map`/`recoverWith`: the `map`/`recoverWith` will end up picking up the changed value.  This inadvertent "closing over" actor state is a longstanding source of nasty bugs in Akka, so it might be worth having a

```scala
val persistenceTarget = persistence
```

and replacing mentions of `persistence` in the ask/`map`/`recoverWith` with `persistenceTarget`: since `persistenceTarget` is a local (and immutable) value, it's safe to close over.

Comment: Thank you! You make solid sense. I would really like to have `persistence` address be returned in the `pipeTo`. Because let's say there's a list of `persistence` and then I wouldn't know which `Persist` message was sent by which `persistence`.

Comment: Got it! I think I'm going to create a wrapper around the response that includes the address and pipe that to self. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Yeah, you can add it in the `map` on the ask future (though you'll want to be careful if `persistence` is some actor-level state, vs. something which you get in the course of processing that particular message: in the former case, I would suggest saving it to a local variable first, otherwise you may have the proverbial rug pulled out from under you)

Comment: I'll edit the answer...